# RestCall with Restsharp not authenticated, it is with Postman

Tags: c#, rest, http, postman, restsharp

I'm trying to get info from a REST endpoint that requires basic authentication.
Using postman I'm fine, getting the information I need from the call:

```
GET endpoint/api/workitems?ids=20449&amp; api-version=2.0 HTTP/1.1
Host: xxx.xxx.xxx.50:8080
Authorization: Basic ABC==,Basic ZZZ    cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e6476d89-ec2b-439d-8821-88ef446a03a9
```

When I do the same with restsharp, I get an Unauthorized error:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.50:8080/endpoint/api/workitems?ids=20449&amp; api-version=2.0");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "06ea7553-d35e-4743-a516-201d6e3b9084");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic ABC==,Basic ZZZ");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't need the `Postman-Token`-Header and your Authorization header looks wrong to me, I believe it can only contain one `Basic`, like `Basic ABC==`, but I'm not sure on this, just haven't seen it be done like this before.

Comment: @TobiasTenglerI think the Postman-Token was irrelevant, but probably the double basic was a problem. I answered myself with a working solution

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I found that the proper way to do the Basic Authentication with restsharp is the following.

It works:

```
var client = new RestClient("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.50:8080/endpoint/api/workitems?ids=20449&amp; api-version=2.0");
client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator(username, decodedToken);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "06ea7553-d35e-4743-a516-201d6e3b9084");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```